# HTML code to send SMS message through a form

Tags: html

I am trying to create an HTML code in order to send SMS messages through a form.
My provider give to me the Http address that i could send these SMS and it looks like bello (of course i have hide passwords, etc)

http://sms.services/send-sms?app-id=108744&password=1111111&to={1}&from=TestSender&message={0}

When i call this address with a phone number instead of {1} and a text insted of {0} it works fine.

But when i try to create the bellow page it says that the attributes are wrong.
Can you please help?

```
<form action="http://sms.services/send-sms?app-id=108744&password=1111111&to=telnumber&from=TestSender&message=textsms" method="post">
<input type="number" name="telnumber" />
<input type="text" name="textsms" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: You should do the actual sending with a server-side language. Otherwise anyone can see the password in the HTML code.

Comment: Yes you are right. This attempt was more to test and understand how the submit command works in such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to `GET`

Make other parameters input type hidden so user will not see those but internally it will be passed.

```
<form action="http://sms.services/send-sms" method="get">
    <input type="number" name="to" />
    <input type="text" name="message" />

    <input type="hidden" name="app-id" value="108744" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="1111111" />
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="TestSender" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Note:** It is not recommended to do like it because it will expose your app-id and password. You should send it to a php or any backend framework and then from there call this.

Comment: In GET method it shouldn't do that.

Comment: And he tried calling address, means he sent using GET and it worked.

Comment: One last challenge for this. And thanks in advance... What if I want to use also hidden type for the message and then i requet the user to enter an attribute in this prefixed message. Meaning for example lets say the text is "Hello, you order with number X is on the way" and the user inputs the X value through the input field.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier you should pass all the data (here number and message) to a backend side. Let the user pass both to the backend and do string manipulation there.

Answer (score -3):

Try to use input type="text" instead of number.
Probably, input type="number" tries to convert string to demical, but your provider use string

Comment: "Probably, input type="number" tries to convert string to demical" — No. Forms don't work that way. URLs don't work that way!